# How to convert values in a specific column in a csv in python?

Tags: python, excel, csv, date-arithmetic

I have a csv file with a lot of data I am looking to edit. I have a column (DJ in excel) that I need to multiply the numbers in the cells by 1.12. I was wondering how I could do that as I have 3800 rows in that single column. Would I have to read the current csv and write it onto a new csv?

This is the code I think I need to enter:

```
#skip header
next(reader, None)

#print new header
writer.writerow(['Data'])

for row in reader:
    newVal = float(row[0]) * 1.12
    writer.writerow([newVal])
```

Not sure how to change the values in the column.

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` would make this pretty trivial:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/filename')
df['columnname'] = df['columnname']*1.12
df.to_csv('path/to/filename')
```

That's it.

Comment: is there a way other than pandas? I cannot seem to install in correctly due to admin restrictions.